70s? Horror story. A demon is assaulting and killing female students in a small town. In the end, the elderly female teacher kills it
Story is probably from the 70s or earlier. Maybe a short story, but I cant be sure. I stopped reading horror stories. (The Amityville Horror novel freaked me out big time and that was about the last horror story I ever read)
I was reading a recent webtoon with a monster who was killing students in a school and the teacher tries to stop it and was killed too, and it reminded me of this story.
In any case, the story was set in a very small town, (maybe with the classic one room school, with an old female teacher, who has been teaching there for many years.) Some of the older female students in the school are being sexually assaulted and killed. If I remember correctly, the police/sheriff/news/gossip was saying that the object they were assaulted with was the diameter of a 4x4" or 6x6" and whether that assault is what killed them, or were killed after the assault I don't remember for sure, but I think they died during the assault due to the size of the object used.
This is a horror story, not porn, and there were no scenes of the assaults in the story. Just vague descriptions of the discovered bodies, and the rumor mill gossiping about what was done.
I think 3-4 girls had been killed at this point.
I believe, one of the male students had been possessed by a demon, or was a monster in disguised, or had a "pet" creature and was looking for a pure students to procreate with/get life essence from/gain more power? He knew one of the girls in the class was a pure and had been arranging to meet them after school, and after transforming into the monster/summoning the demon/calling the creature over, the creature could sense or smell, that the girls were not pure and did it anyway with his tool which was that large, and killed them.
In the end, the teacher figures out who the male student is, based of the victims and his interactions in class with them, and who is the most likely the next victim. That girl is at the school after class studying/cleaning/hiding and the teacher runs to get her out of there before the male student gets there. (She may have called the police/sheriff also.)
Unfortunately she does not get there quick enough. The male student is already there, has the girl pinned down, and is transforming/summoning/calling the monster.
The monster arrives, and knows the pure subject is there. But, just as quickly realizes the student is not pure, and the only other girl in the room, is the old spinster teacher. So it releases the student and heads toward the teacher.
It is only at this point the readers understand why the victims have been chosen, that the monster is looking for virgins.
The monster is then killed. How? I don't know, whether it was she threw some chemistry subject chemicals on it and killed it, or knew it was allergic to some substance and threw it on it, or the police/sheriff arrived just in time and shot it, I don't remember.
In the last few lines of the story, the teacher is thinking she is never going to tell anyone the monster was after virgins, and that she was a virgin, which is why the monster left the girl and switched to attempting to attacking her, that's nobody else's business. (She might have been calling herself Mrs. Teacher for many years so everyone thought she had been married, but she never was, and had never done it.)

Twilla by Tom Reamy, September 1974 F&SF is about a witchy young girl who is far older than she looks and who controls a gigantic demon who likes to rape and kill virgins - the spinster teacher confronts the girl and her demon and finds that she is in more danger than she thought. The girl has been arranging for the deaths of other girls in the class (and playing with the emotions of the boys, just for fun).
Here's a bit of the confrontation with Twilla (the girl):

"I'm ever so glad you decided to pay me a visit, Miss Mahan. It's what
do you say?-killing two birds with one stone?"
"What do you mean?"
"Dazreel has, as I said, limited but strong appetites. If they aren't
satisfied, he becomes quite unmanageable. And don't think he will
reject you because you're a scrawny old crow. He has no taste at all
and only one criterion: virginity." Twilla was almost fidgety with
anticipation.
"What possible difference could it make to that monster?" I must be
losing my mind, Miss Mahan thought. I'm sitting here having a calm
conversation with this wretched child who is going to kill me!
Twilla was thoughtful. "I really don't know. I never thought about it.
That's just the way it's always been It could be a personal
idiosyncrasy, or perhaps it's religious." She shrugged. "Something
like kosher, do you think? Anyway, you can't fool him."
"I don't understand any of this," Miss Mahan said in confusion. "Did
you say he was a . . . a djinn?"
"Surely you've heard of them. King Solomon banished the entire race,
if you remember." She smiled, pleased. "But I saved Dazreel. "
"How old are you?" Miss Mahan breathed.
Twilla chuckled. "You wouldn't believe me if I told you. Don't let the
body mislead you. It's relatively new. Dazreel has great power if you
can control him. But he's crafty and very -literal. One wrong move and
. . ." She ran her forefinger across her throat.
"But . . ." Miss Mahan was completely confused. "If this is all true,
why are you going to school in Hawley, Kansas, for heaven's sake?"
Twilla sighed. "Boredom is the curse of the immortal, Miss Mahan. I
thought it might offer some diversion."

Here's the bit you remember about virginity:

"Dazreel is back upstairs," Twilla assured her, watching her
speculatively. "You have nothing to fear. " She smiled slightly. "He
will have only virgins."  Miss Mahan felt the blood draining from
her face, and she weaved in the chair, feeling the panic creeping
back. Twilla threw her head back, and her crystal laugh was harsh and
strident, like a chandelier tumbling down marble stairs.
"Miss Mahan, you never cease to amaze me," she gasped. "Imagine! And
at your age, too."

The teacher manages to free the demon (by stealing the pendant that controls it) and kill the girl.
Thanks to @user14111 here's a link to the Internet Archive version of the story.

Yes!! I am certain that IS the story I was looking for. and it was a short story. Going to have to check out the IA link and read it again. Thanks for the quick find.

No problem - very memorable story!

Ps. Tom Reamy wrote good stuff. Check out The Detweiler Kid, too

Re-read the story, Looks like I miss remembered quite a bit, there was only 1`dead girl, and "villain" was a practically immortal girl (at least 3000 years old), controlling a djinn.
